# Performance: using Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive, to save user data

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox-api, onedrive

I'm thinking in a free service that offers something like the ability of record and save podcasts, but the costs of storing all those files is making this idea impossible.

I was thinking in saving every user generated file in a storage service (like the ones in the title) and ask permission to the user to manage those drives/folders. That way we wouldn't need a big storage quota, instead the service could be offered free, as we want.

Is this a good idea? In terms of performance.

Comment: performance compared to what? why would a storage service be slower than your custom server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution in the form of the CloudRail single interface for this kind of thing. http://docs.cloudrail.com/docs/getting-started

This allows you to use whatever free Cloud Storage you want, but use the same functions between them.

So for example:

```
cs = new com.cloudrail.si.cloudStorage.OneDrive(
      this, 
      /** Your Client ID **/, 
      /** Your Client Secret**/
    );
```

is how you would substantiate Cloud Storage for OneDrive, and then be able to go on to use cs.upload() for uploading to OneDrive. If you decided to instead use Dropbox, you can switch it over to say "[...] si.cloudStorage.Dropbox" instead.

Full disclaimer: I do work for CloudRail. Please feel free to email me any questions, luke@cloudrail.com